# Topic Identification with WEKA

Tags: weka, data-mining

I am completely new to the field of Data mining and WEKA tool (just installed it today).

I need to do topic identification based on short text sentences.

Let say I have several categories:
 - politics
 - sports
 - other

I am thinking of doing the following:
Have a list of terms that I compare the text to:

- Sports:

  - NFL
  - NBA
  - Touch down
  - etc
- Politics:

  - election
  - president
  - OBama
  - etc

Also, I would like to add more categories.

Then I would apply some algorithm SVM or Naive Bayes with the help of WEKA.

Any idea on how to start doing this with WEKA?

I have searched some tutorials on WEKA but I can't seem to get any examples similar to what I am trying to do.

Any help to start me up will be appreciated.